# Ошибка при создании бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Прохожу урок по созданию ботов на телеге. Вылезает такая ошибка. Хотя ошибки в коде быть не может, так как скопирован с урока. Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста :))

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "bot.py", line 7, in 
>         @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
>       AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Comment: Удалите библиотеку `telebot` и `pytelegrambotapi`, а потом переустановите вторую

Comment: @Dareten Это когда-то помогло и мне. Не могли бы Вы оформить это как ответ, если Вам не сложно?

Answer (score 1):

Удалите библиотеки `telebot` и `pytelegrambotapi`, а потом переустановите вторую.
Библиотека telebot существует, но не имеет отношения к той, которой вы хотите воспользоваться для создания телеграм-бота. К сожалению, название модуля и той библиотеки совпадают и из-за этого могут возникать подобные ошибки